# Parsing CSV file. Separating into more files

Tags: ruby, csv

I am currently working on a small application that will allow someone to enter strings that'll separate a larger file into smaller files.

I am having trouble getting the file to be split into the newer files. This is my code for my CSV method:

```
require 'csv'

new_list = []
old_list = []

def import_csv(file)
  puts "Method begins"
  CSV.foreach("public_schools_list.csv", :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8', :headers => true) do |row|
    if row["company"].downcase.include?("academy" || "lutheran" || "jewish" || "private" || "christian")
      CSV.open("new_list.csv", "ab") do |n|
        n << row

        puts "First Row"

        new_list << n
      end
    else
      CSV.open("old_list.csv", "ab") do |o|
       o << row

       puts "Second Row"

       old_list << o
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "New Csv: #{new_list.count}"
puts "Old Csv: #{old_list.count}"
```

I am just trying to check this code to see if it is splitting the files. I'm not sure if some of this is correct. There are currently only four items in the CSV list. I use the `count` method to check if they go into the correct files.

What code am I missing to get the main file to be separated into two?

here is my controller:

```
include CSVUpload

def import
  csv_separate(params[:file].tempfile)
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

then here is the module i am using:

```
require 'csv'
module CSVUpload

    def csv_separate(file)
        new_list_counter = 0
        old_list_counter = 0

        # puts "Method begins"
        CSV.open("new_list.csv", "ab") do |new_list|
        CSV.open("old_list.csv", "ab") do |old_list|  
            CSV.foreach(file, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8', :headers => true) do |row|
              if row["company"][/\b(?:academy|lutheran|jewish|private|christian)\b/i]
                new_list << row

                new_list_counter += 1
              else
                old_list << row

                old_list_counter += 1
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

and then here is the form:

```
<div>
  <h3>Import a CSV File</h3>
   <%= form_tag({action: "import"}, multipart: true) do %>
   <%= file_field_tag("file") %>
   <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

i hope that helps out a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't open then close the output files for every line you read. That's horribly inefficient and wastes CPU time. Open them outside the `CSV.foreach` loop, then write to them conditionally.

Also, don't aggregate the lines of the file in memory just so you can count them. Instead, increment a counter.

Also, `include?` doesn't work this way:

```
include?("academy" || "lutheran" || "jewish" || "private" || "christian")
```

[The documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-include-3F) says:

```
  str.include? other_str   -> true or false

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns true if str contains the given string orcharacter.

  "hello".include? "lo"   #=> true
  "hello".include? "ol"   #=> false
  "hello".include? ?h     #=> true
```

Notice that it takes a single character or string. Using an or'd list of strings results in only the first string:

```
"academy" || "lutheran" || "jewish" || "private" || "christian" # => "academy"
```

As a result, only "academy" would ever be tested for inclusion.

This is untested but looks right enough:

```
require 'csv'


def import_csv(file)
  new_list_counter = 0
  old_list_counter = 0

  puts "Method begins"

  CSV.open("new_list.csv", "ab") do |new_list|
    CSV.open("old_list.csv", "ab") do |old_list|

      CSV.foreach("public_schools_list.csv", :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8', :headers => true) do |row|

        if row["company"][/\b(?:academy|lutheran|jewish|private|christian)\b/i]
          new_list << row

          puts "First Row"

          new_list_counter += 1

        else
          old_list << row

          puts "Second Row"

          old_list_counter += 1
        end

      end
    end

  end

  puts "New CSV: #{ new_list_counter }"
  puts "Old CSV: #{ old_list_counter }"

end
```

Notice `/\b(?:academy|lutheran|jewish|private|christian)\b/i`. This [tests for multiple sub-strings that are complete words](http://rubular.com/r/gm0BAQwh1e). `\b` in regex-ese means "word-boundary", so each of the embedded words or'd together using `|` are tested separately. `/i` means it's case-insensitive. To accomplish the same thing using `include?` would involve looping over a list of words, which is one of those algorithms that grows slower and slower as you add more words to test.

`row["company"][/\b(?:academy|lutheran|jewish|private|christian)\b/i]` is extremely efficient in comparison to that possible loop-algorithm. Using regex patterns aren't a universal panacea. Used incorrectly regex patterns can actually slow your program, sometimes drastically. Used correctly though, they can reduce your code and, in the right situation, when written correctly, can provide dramatic speed improvements. So, check using benchmarks before you blindly introduce them into code.

Comment: hey thanks man a ton for helping me out! this worked and helped a lot!

Comment: i would upvote it, but i just started here and so i cannot vote yet :/ sorry

Comment: hey @the Tin Man i am wondering if there is a way to make it so that if a user were to type in muplitple strings, and the strings would be from a certain column (ie the company column), and it would be able to split the files into the files by the strings typed. So lets say, I wanted to only put "rows" with the string "academy", "christian", and (lets say) "high". The 'rows' that contained that string in the "company" column would be put into a new list..while those with out those strings would be put into another. idk if this makes since or not. i hope it does. thanks!

Comment: haha i knew that..i dont know why i asked if "theres a way"! there always is! now would i need to look for a gem that could handle that or is there a simple way to do it through the form? i dont want the answer persay, since i would feel like i am not learning (im in training). BUT, if you could point me in the right way that'd help a ton :)

Comment: I have no idea what technology you have wrapped around your code in your question, so it's not possible for me to give you a better answer. Look at your code; You have a conditional test that lets you determine whether to send output to one file or another. Might not that be a good place to have several tests, looking for different words? Where the words come from, and how your code sees them varies greatly depending on whether your code is a command-line app or part of a web site.

Comment: What do you mean 'technology'? (recently new to rails..a few months.)I have integrated the above code into a rails app i am currently working on. In the app the user will be able to select which column and then type in the strings. It'll be a simple app. Mainly just a user can choose what fields and then upload the file and it'll split. For now I am just getting the "type in certain strings that'll split it" part. So, the strings that are typed will be strings within the 'company' column.

Comment: We have no idea what your Rails code looks like. And, how to make this work would be an entirely different question. What you're asking is a standard situation in Rails and all Rails tutorials teach the basics necessary to use values from fields in your controllers.

Comment: oh oaky...my bad..i can post my controller code for the import and the form..its very simple..ill add it to an edit.

Comment: alright i posted it...its in the original...lemme know if it helps at all!

Comment: No, you can't append to the current question, as you've now changed the scope of the problem, and the problem itself. You have to create a new question with the new scope.